# What would a Bandit Kingdom look like and how will it survive?

Tags: society, warfare, medieval, politics, civilization

this question on this platform. My question is that, "What would a Bandit Kingdom look like and how will it survive?" This question had me thinking as I watched a gameplay of a Mount & Blade: Bannerlord modded series with the Banditlord mod. As I watched the series, it had me thinking of what would a late-medieval bandit kingdom or other form of state would look like with it's policies, culture, etc. Most of all, I wonder how it will survive to the fullest like with some kind of civilizational reform.

Comment: Look into the Barbary Coast-era of Northern Africa -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbary_Coast

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is dedicated to providing detailed answers to specific questions you have while building your fictional world. To that end, we need a narrowly-constrained question that will lead to helpful answers. What you have asked here is a build-my-world-for-me question, which would lead to answers that are far too long for the StackExchange format. This question is likely to be put on hold as a result until an [edit] is made to bring it into the scope. if you haven't already, feel free to take the [tour] to get a better understanding of the site

Comment: I tend to agree with @Frostfyre; even as an experienced user, I have found it useful to review the information in the Help Center before posting a question. Also, we have [a dedicated Meta thread](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) called the Sandbox for pre-posting question drafts so that others can review them for problems.

Comment: That being said, I don't think I will [VTC](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7902/70058); you have made an honest attempt to ask a good question, and the question should be fine with a little editing.

Comment: @TheDaleks Note that "a little editing" is _exactly_ why we put questions on hold. (I even mentioned this in my comment.)

Comment: @Frostfyre I tend to try to give new contributors some time to edit their questions before VTC'ing, as I have noticed that it can be dreadfully hard to get a question reopened even after you edit it.

Answer (score 7):

A bandit kingdom meaning that banditry is a significant source of its revenue?

It would be on a trade route that is the only way to move essential trade goods, because that would be the only way for it to avoid simply starving when trade moved elsewhere or just stopped.

It would not last long because if the goods are essential, and this is the only route, all the countries trading *have* to stop the raids to ensure that the goods get through.

Most kingdoms along trade routes made their income off the traders by imposing tariffs and tolls.  Even so, they did not raise enough to really qualify as living off the trade.

Comment: Exactly. This happened along the silk road but also, on a longer scale, from the spices producing lands in South East Asia towards Europe. So much so that a certain Christopher Columbus decided, due also to a gross underestimate of the World size, to cut off the middle men and go to the source of the spices by going West. And so America was discovered. The fruit of a geographical error. ^.^

Comment: Yes. They can get a cut of the action insuring the safety of the trade themselves. Then, ironically, they become about policing these roads.
But if they hit the roads too much either trade will stop or a major power or two will lead an army to squash that kingdom.
Certainly you can't build a kingdom based on loot.
Even in video games that's a bit too much

Comment: It's true that it would not last long... in that form.  The kingdom might be forced to evolve to rely on a more respectable profession.  Transitioning from raiding to militia-enforced tariffs and tolls is not an unrealistic change.